# Importing values from one Enum to another?

Tags: java, enums

Right now, I have two `Enum`s that need to have synchronized values only, and they are present in separate projects. I need to find some way to grab the values from one enum (`Enum1`) and import them into (`Enum2`).

What `Enum1.java` looks like:

```
package com.example.hello;

import com.example.foo.SomeClass;

public enum Enum1 {
     A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4);

     integer i;

     Enum1(int ii) {
         this.i = ii;
     }

     public static int getValue(Enum1 e) {
         return e.i;
     }

     public int doSomething() {
         return SomeClass.doThings(i);
     }
}
```

Meanwhile, `Enum2.java` (in a different project) currently looks like this:

```
package com.example.world;

import com.example.bar.SomeOtherClass;

import static com.example.hello.Enum1.*;

public enum Enum2 {
    // Enums *should* be imported from Enum1

    integer i;

    Enum2(int ii) {
        this.i = ii;
    }

    public int doSomethingElse() {
        return SomeOtherClass.doSomethingElse(i);
    }
}
```

Of course, this isn't working, because the values are not being carried across the gap.

The same reasoning would just be to use `Enum1` in my code, but the functions on the Enums between the two projects needs to be completely different.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, how can I accomplish it in a (relatively) sane way?

---

For context, these two programs use these enums for a permission model. The system checks if a user is at or higher than the minimum required permission level, which could be something like `Enum1.B`. The problem is that `Enum1` depends on a class that I cannot import into the project that contains `Enum2`, because it would be a complete waste to have to bundle a Java dependency with `Enum2`'s project, especially if that project would never be realistically used for any reason.

Eventually, we're going to migrate over to a much more sane permission model where this entire system will be unnecessary, but we need something to work in the meantime, hence the need for a solution (or absolutely filthy hack) of some sort, just to get it working for now.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. Give us a concrete example, anything we can relate to. As posed now, the answer is "no, it's not possible". With context, we could show you alternatives...

Comment: Is it possible to put Enum1 in a project that both project1 and project2 are dependent on?

Comment: @PaulHicks Not really, because such a project doesn't exist. While I could (and probably should) make one, I'd like to avoid complicating this project further.

Comment: @blubb There, I hope that adds enough context for why I need this. I don't post here often, so I'm not 100% sure what "good" context is, so let me know if it's not sufficient.

Comment: From your example, it seems like you don't really need `Enum2`. Consider living without it. If you only need a number in the second project, then just use the number. If you _really_ have to use `Enum2`, then you problably need to review your `doSomethingElse` logic every time `Enum1` changes. In which case, code generation isn't the best answer. You would better off with (test-time) static analysis that asserts that `Enum2` contains all the values in `Enum1`. That way you can manually review `doSomethingElse` and update `Enum2` when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve this through code generation.
Somewhere in your build process of the project containing Enum2, read the Enum1 and create the Enum2 in a generated-source folder. All major build systems and IDEs do a good job at supporting generated code.

And for the actual code generation, you basically have 3 options:

- Template-based, using a template framework like Velocity or Moustache
- AST-based, using a code generator framework like [JCodeModel](https://github.com/phax/jcodemodel)
- Do-it-yourself with good old string concatenation

I have [an example project](https://github.com/mostlymagic/hacking-java/tree/master/1_valueobjects/4_jcodemodel) from a conference talk of mine, where I show how to integrate JCodeModel with a Maven build using Groovy. You can use it as a starting point.